# Failed to start network manager wait online stuck not booting kali Linux

Tags: linux-kernel, kali-linux

Can anyone help I'm getting this error failed to start network manager wait online but don't boot up I have posted the error message picture

[image]

Comment: Btw, I think the main issue is related to the ACPI errors. Are you booting from virtual machine or in *bare-metal*?

Comment: No not through virtual machines just the core system

Comment: Have you tried installing another distro? Maybe the issue is with Kali (I think is about hardware, though). If another distro works (such as Ubuntu) then you can install the kali tools in that distro.

Comment: Hardware is fine it just the kali Linux I got this issue yesterday before I was using the os